# How to integrate Parasoft (JTest) in Hudson?

Tags: hudson, maven-3, hudson-plugins, parasoft, jtest

I normally use JTest Parasoft as a plugin in Eclipse.

But now, I need to integrate JTest in Hudson, at a way that in the Post-build, JTest should run its tests over a Maven project.

So my questions are :

1. How to integrate JTest in Hudson? I found a plugin CppTest by Parasoft and not JTest...
2. How to specify the tests which should be run on the project? For example, configure JTest to run "Find unused code" which is included in "Static Analysis"...?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jtest has fully functional command line interface so generally integration should not be a problem.

As for your questions:

1) there is a Jtest plugin for Maven, so you will be able to trigger your post-build action easily. It's thoroughly described on http://build.parasoft.com .

2) you can specify the Test Configuration of your choice by using -Dparasoft.config option (i.e.: mvn parasoft:jtest -Dparasoft.config="user://Unused Code").

You can find all the parameters which can be used with parasoft:jtest goal described here: http://build.parasoft.com/docs/maven-parasoft-plugin/jtest-mojo.html .

Answer (score 1):

- We have integrated Jenkins with Jtest (*Linux*)
- Downloaded the Jtest installers and installed in Jenkins server (in slaves too if you have slaves attached)
- Env variables for same has been set (*JTEST_HOME*)
- And now without any entries for Jtest in Pom or build.xml files, we
  can directly call the jtestcli commands either in invoke shell
  section or use Jtest goals with maven too.

We need to make sure that we have `maven-parasoft-plugin 3.12` and Jtest dependencies available in maven repo (for maven projects) and we should have `parasoft-ant-3.12.jar` available which we need to place in ant lib folder (for ant projects).